# Graph arbitrary data on the command line

Tags: monitoring, command-line-interface, postgresql, graph

I'm currently debugging an issue where I see a large number of threads in my application hanging on to a database connection even though they are asleep, often the threads sleep for a significant length of time (10-300s) (they're sensor reading/normality checking threads; that's not important)

I wanted to know if there's a decent way to graph something like:

```
watch "echo select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where procpid <> pg_backend_pid(); | psql"
```

and have it shown in the CLI or as an image that I can simply open, or write the image at the end of the run?

Surely there's a unix tool for histograms over time using the CLI to draw it (curses)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about a curses based solution back for graphing arbitrary data gnuplot can be of help. The relevant URL http://www.gnuplot.info/ . It is quite complex but for basic things the documentation should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

`gnuplot` is one option for this, but it's a bit awkward if you want a continuous feed of data. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123378/398670) suggests that you could use [eplot](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/eplot/index.html) for more convenient terminal output.